# How to insert a file into a MySQL database via a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

Having submitted a form with a file to upload, I'm having trouble trying to insert it into the longblob field on the image table when using a stored procedure to handle the insert.

Usual basics are set up, multipart/form-data enctype for form, file type for input.  When I submit the form and just embedded mysql call in PHP, it uploads the file to the table correctly, just when I pass the details through to the sp, it falls over.

Is there a way to insert the filedata into the blob field via the sp, or is it just going to have to have embedded sql calls in the code?

Comment: Advice, don't save it in blob field. Might get sluggish over time and growt could be kinda explosive.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function%5Fload-file or http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/643396-how-store-images-binary-data-mysql-database-using-blob-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Alfabravo, Why not just save the file to a dedicated folder and save a link, or path or just the filename  of the file to the database?

Comment: Managed to do this in the end, but as so many other posts have suggested, ended up using the file server instead.  This was more of a 'can I' rather than 'should I' initially, just to see if it could be done.  Cheers though.